# How do I set the range selector to go back to a specific time in plotly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have a plotly chart that uses a range selector that looks like this-

```
fig.update_layout(
xaxis=dict(
    rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(count=1,
                 label="1d",
                 step="day",
                 stepmode="backward")
        ])
    )
    type="date"
)
```

I pulled this example code from the wiki [here](https://plotly.com/python/range-slider/).

Right now, this code sets the chart to show the most recent 24 hours. Instead, I want the chart to show data after 9am this morning. Can I use the range selector to tell plotly to show data after 9am from the current day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot specify a time the way you mentioned. But you can decrease the window for the rangeselector to an hourly range (something like 12 hours or so).

```
fig.update_layout(
xaxis=dict(
    rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(count=12,
                 label="12hr",
                 step="hour",
                 stepmode="backward")
        ])
    )
    type="date"
)
```

Comment: I suppose I could set the count to be a variable where it always ends up setting the chart to 9am

Comment: Yup thats how I would do it